# How should a controller with @Method("post")  handle the request if submitted form is not valid?

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a controller in symfony2 like below, if the user form is valid it will redirect to some other link but if there is some error it will remain in the same page and shows the errors. simply general scenario when the client side validation is disabled and only sever side validation is checking for the errors.

```
/**
 * Creates a new User entity.
 *
 * @Route("/create", name="admin_user_create")
 * @Method("post")
 * @Template("UserBundle:User:new.html.twig")
 */
public function createAction()
{
    $entity  = new User();
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $form    = $this->createForm(new UserType() , $entity);

    $form->bindRequest($request);
    if($form->isValid())
    {
        // DO SOMETHING ... 
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('some_link' , array( 'user_id' => $entity->getId() )));
    }

    // If the form is NOT valid, it will render the template and shows the errors.   
    return array(
        'entity' => $entity ,
        'form'   => $form->createView()
    );
}
```

Scenario would be something like below:

1. User input some invalid data for the form
2. User submit the form
3. Controller check if the form is valid
4. Since it is not valid it will render the template, in this case

   ```
   @Template("UserBundle:User:new.html.twig")
   ```
5. The route in the browser will be `/create`
6. If the user `click` on browser link and it not `post` will get an error

How can I fix this ? Do I have to redirect again? Since the method is `post` is it possible to redirect ?

Comment: Can I suggest you create another question for the question at the bottom of your post as it is unrelated to your question title and I think you will get a better response if it is a separate discussion.

Comment: Sure, I asked it here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547871/how-to-avoid-form-re-submission-if-browser-back-button-is-selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't specify the @Method("POST") and do this in the method:

```
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
{
    $form->bindRequest($request);
    if($form->isValid())
    {
        // DO SOMETHING ... 
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('some_link' , array( 'user_id' => $entity->getId() )));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accept `GET` or `POST` and do something link:

```
/**
 * Creates a new User entity.
 *
 * @Route("/create", name="admin_user_create")
 * @Method("GET|POST")
 * @Template("UserBundle:User:new.html.twig")
 */
public function createAction()
{
    $entity  = new User();
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $form    = $this->createForm(new UserType() , $entity);

    // Is this POST? Bind the form...
    if('POST' == $request->getMethod()) $form->bindRequest($request);

    // GET or from not valid? Return the view...
    if('GET' == $request->getMethod() || !$form->isValid()) :
        return array(
            'entity' => $entity ,
            'form'   => $form->createView()
        );
    endif;

    // Success, then persist the entity and redirect the user
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('some_link',
        array('user_id' => $entity->getId()))
    );
}
```

Comment: You cannot call `$form->isValid()` when you don't have `$form->bindRequest($request)`.

Comment: @PMoubed there is bindRequest. In fact. when method is POST first "if" calls bindRequest. The same happens for the second "if".

Comment: You only bindRequest when method is POST, right? So if method is GET bindRequest never get called. I am saying you only can call  $form->isValid() without bindRequest throw an exception.

Comment: @PMoubed operator is `||` short-circuit http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php. You can call `bindRequest` only on POST: when method is GET `$form->isValid()` isn't invoked because the first condition evaluates `true` and soon `if` is executed; the second condition `isValid` isn't evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Creates a new User entity.
 *
 * @Route("/create", name="admin_user_create")
 * @Method("GET|POST")
 * @Template("Use`enter code here`rBundle:User:new.html.twig")
 */
public function createAction()
{
    $entity  = new User();
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $form    = $this->createForm(new UserType() , $entity);
// Is this POST? Bind the form...
if('POST' == $request->getMethod()) $form->bindRequest($request);

// GET or from not valid? Return the view...
if('GET' == $request->getMethod() || !$form->isValid()) :
    return array(
        'entity' => $entity ,
        'form'   => $form->createView()
    );
endif;

// Success, then persist the entity and redirect the user
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('some_link',
    array('user_id' => $entity->getId()))
);
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SO. DOn't just put some code. An explanation will be good. :)